# React native, edit data from another screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I made 2 screens one home screen and 2nd edit screen I need to edit data of home screen from edit screen and save it and that data should also update in home and detail screen. How can I do this without redux or context. Can anyone tell me.

Home.js

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    post: [
      {
        key: "1",
        title: "A Good Boi",
        des: "He's a good boi and every one know it.",
        image: require("../assets/dog.jpg"),
      },
    ],
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.post}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <>
              <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.7}
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Edit", item)}
                style={styles.Edit}
              >
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="playlist-edit"
                  color="green"
                  size={35}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Card
                title={item.title}
                subTitle={item.des}
                image={item.image}
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Details", item)}
              />
            </>
          )}
        />
```

Edit.js

```
class ListDetails extends Component {
  render() {
    const listing = this.props.route.params;
    return (
      <View>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={listing.image} />
        <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
          <AppTextInput value={listing.title} />
          <AppTextInput value={listing.des} />
        </View>
        <AppButton
          text="Save"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack("Home")}
        />
      </View>
```

Details.js

```
 const listing = this.props.route.params;
    return (
      <View>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={listing.image} />
        <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{listing.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.des}>{listing.des}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
```

Comment: You might wanna do it with `global` and event emitters

Comment: how can I do it with global and event emitter? never heard about that before any tutorial link you can suggest?

Comment: You can do this with MobX Store. It's super simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a function from your home screen to **setState** for it in your edit screen. In case navigating to edit screen causes the home screen unmounted, you can change the **navigate** method to [push](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#push) of stack navigator (I haven't tested yet). The code now should look like:

HomeScreen.js:

```
onEdit=(data)=>{
  setState(...);
}
...
<TouchableOpacity
  activeOpacity={0.7}
  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Edit", {item, onEdit})} //use push instead if error occured
  style={styles.Edit}
>
...
```

Edit.js

```
class ListDetails extends Component {
  render() {
    const {item:listing, onEdit} = this.props.route.params;
    return (
      <View>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={listing.image} />
        <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
          <AppTextInput value={listing.title} />
          <AppTextInput value={listing.des} />
        </View>
        <AppButton
          text="Save"
          onPress={() => { onEdit(...); this.props.navigation.goBack("Home");}}
        />
      </View>
```

Comment: sorry for stupid questions I'm new in react native, but how can I pass data in home.js onEdit function is it like `this.setState({post: { title: data  }})` ??

Comment: You can easily pass data you want from Edit screen to the onEdit function like this:

`onPress={() => { onEdit(dataYouWant); this.props.navigation.goBack("Home");}}`

Comment: can you please give an example like I want to change title please please

Comment: First you should have a **state** on Edit screen to store value that user enters. Then the onPress function of **AppButton** should be: `onPress={() => { onEdit(this.state); this.props.navigation.goBack("Home");}}`. So on the definition of **onEdit** function of Home.js you can use it as data: `onEdit=(data)=>{
   this.setState({post: { title: data  }})
}
` The **data** parameter on Home.js is exactly **this.state** on Edit.js. Sorry I can't write full code because comments have character limitation.

Comment: no problem i got it i will try this and let you know if it work or not, thank you so much for help

Comment: well it's not picking onEdit `Can't find variable: onEdit`

Comment: and I set onEdit like you said but how to handle onChangeText? without that i can't change value

Comment: onChangeText usage on this link: https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput.    About the bug, I checked and realized I wrote a bit wrong in Home.js. You can change the Home.js to this:
`<TouchableOpacity
  activeOpacity={0.7}
  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Edit", {item, onEdit: this.onEdit})}
  style={styles.Edit}
>`

Comment: i know how to use onChangeText, i mean to say what should I pass in it I tried `onChangeText = {(text)=> listing.title(text)}` but it didn't worked

Comment: You can't do that. **listing.title** is a value, not a function so it can't be call with ( ). You should do `onChangeText = {(text)=> this.setState(text)}`. Alright the document above doesn't use class component so you may be confused. Here is the way of onChangeText using class component: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/react-native/handling-text-input/

Comment: Thnx for help

Comment: Glad to help you. Can you upvote or mark my answer as solution pls 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222635/discussion-between-kanwarjeet-singh-and-thanh-chng).

Comment: Hye, I did that onChangeText but it's showing an error `setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables`