# React native, undefined is not an object And handle onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I made 2 screens home and editing screen. I want to change values from edit screen without redux and context but I don't know how? and also when I click save in editscreen it's throwing error that `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.goBack')` and displaing blank home screencwhy that's happening. Can some one help me please, below is my code

home.js

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    modal: false,
    editMode: false.
    post: [
      {
        key: "1",
        title: "A Good Boi",
        des: "He's a good boi and every one know it.",
        image: require("../assets/dog.jpg"),
      },
      {
        key: "2",
        title: "John Cena",
        des: "As you can see, You can't see me!",
        image: require("../assets/cena.jpg"),
      },
    ],
  };

  addPost = (posts) => {
    posts.key = Math.random().toString();
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        post: [...prevState.post, posts],
        modal: false,
      };
    });
  };

  onEdit = (data) => {
    this.setState({ post: { title: data }, editMode: false });
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.editMode)
      return <EditScreen item={item} onEdit={this.onEdit} />;
    return (
      <Screen style={styles.screen}>
        <Modal visible={this.state.modal} animationType="slide">
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
            <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
            
              <AddPost addPost={this.addPost} />
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </Modal>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.post}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <>
            
              <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.7}
                onPress={() => this.setState({ editMode: true })}
                style={styles.Edit}
              >
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="playlist-edit"
                  color="green"
                  size={35}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Card>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={item.image} />
                <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
                  <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={1}>
                    {item.title}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.subTitle} numberOfLines={2}>
                    {item.des}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </Card>
            </>
          )}
        />
      </Screen>
```

Edit.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, KeyboardAvoidingView } from "react-native";

import colors from "../config/colors";
import AppButton from "../components/AppButton";
import AppTextInput from "../components/AppTextInput";

class EditScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    const { item, onEdit, onClose } = this.props;
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior="position"
        keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 0 : 100}
      >
        <Image style={styles.image} source={item.image} />
        <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
          <AppTextInput value={item.title} />
          <AppTextInput value={item.des} />
        </View>
        <AppButton
          text="Save"
          onPress={() => {
            onEdit(this.state);
          }}
        />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
export default EditScreen;
```

AppTextInput.js

```
function AppTextInput({ icon, width = "100%", ...otherProps }) {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, { width }]}>
      <TextInput
        placeholderTextColor={defaultStyles.colors.medium}
        style={defaultStyles.text}
        {...otherProps}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React native, edit data from another screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220511/react-native-edit-data-from-another-screen)

Comment: nop, i'm still looking for ans

Comment: I got it but the question is the same; you should not create a new one.

Comment: Ii know but I need answer and no one is answering  that question so don't have any other choice I need help :')

Comment: Well, this is not a professional service, it is a community-driven tool; sometimes you receive the answer you need, sometimes you don't. Not receiving the an answer to your question is not a reason to ignore the rules of this community.

Comment: okk i will remember that

Comment: can you help???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Edit.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';

import colors from '../config/colors';
import AppButton from '../components/AppButton';
import AppTextInput from '../components/AppTextInput';

class EditScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ...props.item };
  }

  render() {
    const { onEdit, onClose } = this.props;
    const { title, des, image } = this.state;
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior="position"
        keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 100}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={image} />
        <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
          <AppTextInput
            value={title}
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({ title: text })}
          />
          <AppTextInput
            value={des}
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({ des: text })}
          />
        </View>
        <AppButton text="Save" onPress={() => onEdit(this.state)} />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
export default EditScreen;
```

onEdit

```
onEdit = data => {
  const newPosts = this.state.post.map(item => {
    if(item.key === data.key) return data;
    else return item;
  })
  this.setState({ post: newPosts, editMode: false });
};
```

Comment: still unable to edit and getting error when clicking save `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.posts.map')`

Comment: sorry it wast this.state.post. let me know if that works

Comment: also onChangeText instead of onTextChange. copy the edited response

Comment: can you explain code lil bit please so I can explain it to someone

Comment: can you explain code lil bit please, I'm new to react native I'm still learning thinks long way to go

Comment: So basically you send item which is the post to editscreen. When the editscreen is instantiated we create a state with all the info of the post this line. `this.state = { ...props.item };`. then we have a texinput that get the value of title from the state and then when the field changes the onChangeText is triggered and we update the state. When the submit button is clicked we send the data in the state to on edit and that uses it to map over the posts and replace the post you edited with the data you sent from the state.

Comment: can you look at that one please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64219653/react-native-invaild-prop-source

Answer (score 0):

Only the direct children of a navigator can access

> this.props.navigation

If you want to access that inside the edit screen you can pass it from the Home screen as a prop. Like so:

```
      return <EditScreen item={item} onEdit={this.onEdit} navigation={this.props.navigation} />;
```

But i don't think you need to go back because you are still on the Home page and just rendering the EditScreen within it. So just changing the state to have editMode: false should be enough

Comment: onPress on AppButton you are calling onEdit which does this `this.setState({ post: { title: data }, editMode: false });` right ? setting editMode to false

Comment: oh ya, that's silly mistake but it's not rendering data after save

Comment: it's because you are setting the post to `post: { title: data }` instead post should be an array with all the posts

Comment: how can i fix that

Comment: can you please edit your question and paste all the Edit.js file please so i can take a look at it.

Comment: So in EditScreen you don't even have a state declared so when you are sending ` onEdit(this.state);` this.state is null. You would need to add a state in there and on the AppTextInput onChange you would need to change that state and then send it on button pressed. if you want me to try sending something that works i need you to edit your question and add AppTextInput in there as well.

Comment: done, and can you also tell me how can I handle onChange in EditScreen with an example like i can't use setSTateThere so how can I?